# Using application class to store data

Tags: java, android

### I am using application class. to store golbal data of `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist` structure

---

**Error i am facing**:

- In the `ResultActivity.java` at line `ArrayAdapter<String>
  adapter=new
  ArrayAdapter<String>(ResultActivity.this,R.layout.custom_single_list,R.id.textView1,
  arraylist);`
- I am getting error as :: `The constructor
  ArrayAdapter<String>(ResultActivity, int, int,
  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) is undefined`
- what i need to modify in `ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype.java`

---

**BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.java**

```
public class BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters extends Activity{
    // Declare Variables
        JSONObject jsonobject;
        JSONArray jsonarray;
        ListView listview;
        ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype adapter;
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
        static String NAME = "rank";
        Button btn;

        String TYPE_FILTER;

        StringBuilder result;


        MyApplication mApplication;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            mApplication = (MyApplication)getApplication();

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Get the view from listview_main.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

            TYPE_FILTER = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key_title");
            Log.v("---- Value-Start---", TYPE_FILTER);
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    result = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                        if (adapter.mysparse.get(i) == true) {

                            result.append(arraylist.get(i).get(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.NAME));
                            result.append("\n");
                        }

                    }
                    Intent n = new Intent(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    n.putExtra("buffer", result.toString());
                    startActivity(n);
                }
            });

            // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
            new DownloadJSON().execute();
        }

        // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.this);
                // Set progressdialog title
                //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Fetching the information");
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Create an array
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                String newurl = "?" + "Key=" + TYPE_FILTER;


                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://54.218.73.244:7005/RestaurantAtomicListItemType/"+newurl);

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.NAME, jsonobject.getString("MasterListMenuName"));

                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
                // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
                adapter = new ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.this, arraylist);
                // Set the adapter to the ListView

                mApplication.setArrayListMapData(arraylist);

                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                // Close the progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

**ResultActivity.java**

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> myList;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    String myName;

    MyApplication mApplication;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mApplication = (MyApplication)getApplication();

        arraylist = mApplication.getArrayListMapData();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        Intent n = getIntent();
        myName = n.getStringExtra("buffer");

        myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData);

        myList.add(myName);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ResultActivity.this,R.layout.custom_single_list,R.id.textView1, arraylist);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

**ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype.java**

```
public class ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype extends BaseAdapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    SparseBooleanArray mysparse;

    public ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        mysparse = new SparseBooleanArray(data.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView name;
        CheckBox chk;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_for_atomic_list_item_type, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_id_atomic_list_item_type);
        chk = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_atomic_list_item_type_id);


        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        name.setText(resultp.get(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.NAME));

        chk.setTag(position);
        chk.setChecked(mysparse.get(position, false));
        chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return itemView;
    }

    public boolean isChecked(int position) {
        return mysparse.get(position, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mysparse.put(position, isChecked);

    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mysparse.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }
}
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void setArrayListMapData(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> setData)
    {
        arraylist = setData;
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getArrayListMapData()
    {
        return arraylist;
    }
}
```

**custom_single_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

---

### {EDIT}

**ResultActivity.java**

```
public class ResultActivity extends ListActivity {

    ListView lstView; 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 
    String myName;
    MyApplication mApplication;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put("key", "value"+i);
            arraylist.add(map);

        }

        String[] from = { "key" };
        int[] to = { R.id.textView1 };
        SimpleAdapter adapter= new SimpleAdapter(this, arraylist,R.layout.custom_single_list, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

**Log**::

```
01-03 12:48:40.088: D/AndroidRuntime(267): Shutting down VM
01-03 12:48:40.098: W/dalvikvm(267): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.multitabcheckboxselection/com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.multitabcheckboxselection/com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.multitabcheckboxselection/com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems.onCreate(BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems.java:36)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  ... 11 more
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at com.example.multitabcheckboxselection.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.onCreate(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.java:43)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-03 12:48:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  ... 20 more
01-03 12:53:40.568: I/Process(267): Sending signal. PID: 267 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you post `custom_single_list.xml`?

Comment: @Raghunandan .... i have posted the  custom_single_list.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ResultActivity.this,R.layout.custom_single_list,R.id.textView1, arraylist)
```

Your ArrayList is `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist`. its not `ArrayList<String>`. But you have `new ArrayAdapter<String>`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

You have a custom adapter. SO i guess you need to set the custom adapter to listview.

You can also use a custom adapter also.

Edit:

```
String[] from = { "key" }; // map key
int[] to = { R.id.textView1 };// id of textview
SimpleAdapter adapter= new SimpleAdapter(ActivityName.this,arraylist ,R.layout.custom_single_list, from, to);
```

Exmaple:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{

    ListView lstView; 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        lstView = getListView();
        lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);    
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put("key", "value"+i);
            arraylist.add(map);

        }
        String[] from = { "key" };
        int[] to = { R.id.textView1 };
        SimpleAdapter adapter= new SimpleAdapter(this, arraylist,R.layout.row, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }   

}
```

I have a row.xml with `TextView` with id `textView1`. You can have more textviews and display the data according to your requirement.

Snap

[image]

Comment: Can you show me a example .... some backbone of code ... im confused should i make a custom adapter extending base adapter or anything else

Comment: @smriti3 i have see many of your posts where you use custom adapter. In you post itself you have a custom adapter. SO what is the confusion

Comment: I have used but ...this requirement i am getting confused like should i need to make a adapter extending ArrayAdapter<String> or just BaseAdapter ....thats y was asking a overall structure ....

Comment: @smriti3 you can use a SimpleAdapter also check my eidt

Comment: @smriti3 i am confused. Makes no sense. Specify the confusion part. you have a custom adapter in your post. what is the purpose of that??

Comment: [+1] for your help ... sorry i am new to managing adapter stuff in android .... i did made all the changes as u advised ..... but please see the edit

Comment: @smriti3 what is line 43 `BLD_IndividualListOfItems_Starters.java`? You should look a the stack trace and debug. It looks like you have a classcastexception. This has nothing to do with ResultActivity

Comment: @smriti3 http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android. is this the line 43  `mApplication = (MyApplication)getApplication();`.

Comment: Looks like i have declared in manifest properly .... its better i make new question

Comment: @smriti3 why new question post line 43. if you wish to post a new question go ahead with it. But make sure its not a duplicate